# Showing that the linear twist map is sensitive dependent

Tags: analysis, modular-arithmetic, special-functions, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

[image]

[image]

Choose $\Delta=\frac{1}{2}$  (I believe this value should work). let $\delta > 0$ and let $\textbf{x}_1=(x_1,y_1) \in X$.  I assuming that $d$ is the Euclidean distance.

Somehow I think we need to pick two points with the same $x$ value$(=x_1)$ that are somewhat close enough in the vertical direction. Having problems writing this formally.

I start by writing $T^n(x_1,y_1)=(x_1+ny_1 \mod 1, ny_1 \mod 1)$ and $T^n(x_1,y_2)=(x_1+ny_2 \mod1, ny_2 \mod 1)$. Then I cannot see how to proceed. I cannot see how to choose my $n$ or my $\textbf{x}_2=(x_1,y_2) \in X$ such that the $y$'s are right distance away.

Apparently a hint is that somehow $x_1+ny_1=x_1+ny_2 +n(y_2-y_1)$.

Comment: You need to show that when $x_1$ and $x_2$ are close and $y_1$ and $y_2$ are close, there is possibility that $T^(x_1,y_1)$ and $T^(x_1,y_1)$ are far away. As you showed that for the first coordinate $x_1+ny_1=x_1+ny_2 +n(y_2-y_1)$. Even $y_2-y_1$ is very small, when $n$ is large enough such that $n(y_2-y_1)$ is close to $1/2$ and you can see from that the map is sensitive dependent on initial conditions.

Comment: Could you write what you are saying in a bit more detail please? I feel that this at the moment is what my question described

Comment: OK, I will write it in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $\Delta\leq1/2$, for a point $(x_1,y_1)$ and $\delta>0$ we choose $m$ such that $1/2^{m+1}<\delta$ and let $x_2=x_1$ and $y_2=y_1+1/2^{m+1}$. Let $n=2^m$ then we have that $n(y_2-y_1)=1/2$ and so $T^n(x_1,y_1)=T^n(x_2,y_2)+(1/2,0)$ and we see the two points have distance 1/2 greater than or equal to $\Delta$.

Comment: how have you just ignored the mod 1's?

Comment: All the equalities are in the mod 1 sense.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what do you mean by last question?

Comment: Your first comment on your answer i am unclear about its meaning

Comment: You said how I ignored the mod 1's, and I think all the equalities are in the mod 1 sense such that $x=y$ means $x=y(mod 1)$.